# How to send a jsonObject with array of images and other details using retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, request, retrofit2

When I try that [request in POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6pFO.jpg), it works fine.
However, when I try to do the same using retrofit 2.0; I always received error 500 and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong!

The code below is the call using retrofit:

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("relatorio/{token}")
Call<JsonObject> uploadJson(@Path("token") String token, @Body JsonObject auditoria);

Call<JsonObject> call = uploadJson(details.get(KEY_TOKEN), json);
```

And, here I have the construction of the parameters passed in the call:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
JsonArray steps = new JsonArray();
steps.add(new JsonParser().parse(data.getStringExtra("json")).getAsJsonObject());
json.add("steps", steps);
json.addProperty("title", basic.getString("title"));
json.addProperty("description", basic.getString("description"));
json.addProperty("autor", basic.getString("autor"));
json.addProperty("responsavel", details.get(KEY_USERNAME));
json.add("imagens", prepare());

private JsonArray prepare(){
    Set<String> keys = JsonFormFragmentPresenter.imagesList.keySet();
    JsonArray imagens = new JsonArray();

    for(String k : keys){
        for(String path : JsonFormFragmentPresenter.imagesList.get(k)){
            if(!path.equals(null) && !path.equals("")){
                imagens.add(path);
            }
        }
    }

    JsonFormFragmentPresenter.imagesList.clear();
    return imagens;
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Multipart Format

Here is a Conde Sample Below

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/contact/image")
    Call<Response> ImageUpload(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    @Multipart
    @POST("sync/image")
    Call<ResponseBody> MultiImageUpload(@PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> mapFileAndName);


 public static HashMap<String, RequestBody> GetAllImage(Context context) {
        File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/.ELMEX");
        File[] filesArray = files.listFiles();
        List<File> listOfNames = Arrays.asList(filesArray);
        HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>(listOfNames.size());
        RequestBody file = null;

        for (int i = 0, size = listOfNames.size(); i < size; i++) {
            file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), listOfNames.get(i));
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + listOfNames.get(i).getName() + ".jpg", file);
            file = null;
        }

        return  map;
    }


 HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = UtilImage.GetAllImage(context);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = Retro.getRetroWS().MultiImageUpload(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I will try that code; however, it is only sending the images right? I also, need to send other JSON fields.

Comment: It still returning erro 500